# Support Windows Server 2016 Active Directory?

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory, principalcontext

I have a Winform Client that use Windows Active Directory to get the current Windows account name.

Is there any way to know if this solution will work with the new Windows Server 2016 Active Directory without setting it up?

**Client code**

```
            public string GetCurrentActiveDirectoryAccountName()
            {
                var windowsName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
                var index = windowsName.LastIndexOf("\\");
                if (index > 0)
                    windowsName = windowsName.Substring(index + 1);

                return windowsName;
            }

        public void AuthenticateActiveDirectoryAccount(string username, string password)
        {
            //Hidden code to setup variables 

            if (ADUserName.Length > 0)
                context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ADServer, ADUserName, ADUserPassword);
            else
                context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ADServer);

            using (context)
            {
                if (!context.ValidateCredentials(account, password))
                    //Hidden code to throw exception
            }
        }

        public string CheckActiveDirectoryAccount(string account)
        {
            ///Hidden code to setup variables

            if (ADUserName.Length > 0)
                context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ADServer, null, ADUserName, ADUserPassword);
            else
                context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ADServer);

            using (context)
            {
                if ((user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, account)) == null)
                {
                    if (account.Contains("\\"))
                    {
                        userPrincipalNameList = user.UserPrincipalName.Split('\\').ToList();

                        if (userPrincipalNameList.Count > 0)
                            user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, userPrincipalNameList[0]);
                    }
                }

                if (user != null)
                {
                    using (user)
                    {
                        userAccount = user.SamAccountName;
                        return userAccount.ToLower();
                    }
                }
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hade to setup a test with Microsoft Windows Server 2016 as as expected my AD integration works just as fine.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is historically pretty careful with being backwards-compatible. This is why you can still run DOS programs in Windows 10.

With AD, they don't usually remove features. They only add them. Take a look at the this article to see what's new in AD for Server 2016: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/whats-new-active-directory-domain-services

I would expect all of that to work with AD running on Server 2016.